# How to manage individual mailbox of the batch migration?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, exchange-migration, exchange-hybrid

I tried to migrate 4 mailboxes in a batch migration with 'manually complete' is on.

When the synchronization is done, I noticed 1 of them is failed, I know how to fix the failed box. But the question is, according to the plan the other 3 mailboxes should be finalized today.

If I click "complete this migration batch" without fixing anything, what will happen to the 3 successful mailboxes and the failed one?

After I correct the setting of the failed mail, how can I successfully restart synchronized just for the fail mailbox?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command to resume or remove the failed move request from the batch:

```
Get-MoveRequest "Failed User mailbox"|Resume-Moverequest
```

Here is a blog would give you some hints:
[Completing Individual Move Requests from a Migration Batch](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/completing-individual-move-requests-migration-batch/)